# How do I add a Send to Myself link in the Share menu of iOS?

Tags: ios, email, shortcut

in iOS, when I'm reading an article or when I see a picture I want to save, I just click on Share and use Mail to send it to my own email box.

During a few days I had the opportunity to send it to my mail by using the Favorites line in Share menu but now it only contains sending text messages to friends.

Is it possible to configure this Favorites line in Share Menu ?

Or if not, is there a way to make a Shortcut that would automatically take the item i want to share and send it to a pre-configured email box in just one tap ?

Thanks

Comment: What app do you read articles in? What app is your mail in? Have you considered a bookmark manager that allows tagging and archiving instead of overloading mail? https://pinboard.in/

Comment: Tweetbot or Photos or anything I read something in and want to send it to me by email because email is the place where i stock everything i need to do

Comment: Cool. If email works, that’s great. If the answers you get don’t work in all your apps, an edit to the question to explain will bump it and perhaps get more broad answers. Most of us that have seen it have a different workflow but surely in a week you’ll get lots of views

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it works on suggestions and you changed nothing in email configurations, best shot is to take the pain of using the longer route. Send some emails to yourself and it should be back.

Also consider using reading list in Safari.

For shortcuts in iOS, see https://support.apple.com/HT208309

Comment: That's what i thought but even after dozens of email-to-myself usage and absolutely no sharing to anyone in the favorites, it still doesn't appear...